# Can you create rooms in Google Chat using Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm currently developing a workflow tool and would like to integrate the ability to store links to chat rooms into my google sheet.

Is there a way I can create rooms in Google Chat using Google Apps script?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 4):

At the moment there doesn't appear to be a programmatic way to create a room. This is a likely due to the fact that having a script or bot that could create rooms could potentially spam room creation (whether intentionally or unintentionally). It's possible this could change in the future (likely with some limitations), but nothing has been confirmed by Google yet. Right now rooms can only be created manually through the UI.

### Reference

- [Google Chat API](https://developers.google.com/chat/reference/rest)

Comment: Ah thats a shame, appreciate the response. Thank you!